# Can Django translation be performed offline?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.6 for localization and Underscore.js for templating. I'm new to Django, and I'm wondering: Does it offer a command-line tool or some other method for translating templates beforehand?

The idea would be to end up with a file structure like this...

```
templates
|-- en
|   |-- some-template.html
|-- es
|   |-- some-template.html
|-- fr
    |-- some-template.html
```

...and then throw it all on an S3 instance and eliminate Django's runtime translation overhead.

Comment: It's still a template though - are you sure putting them on S3 is going to deliver a performance benefit? It seems to me it might be better to use the template cache tags to store responses per-language instead. That's the standard approach for improvement performance overhead in other instances, and it seems like it would be appropriate here too.

Comment: Right now we only have EC2 instances running Django. Some client requests need both data (from the database) and a translated Underscore template; however, many client requests only need the template. The goal is to split up our requests so that those which need data go to a 'back-end' server, while those that only need the template go to a 'front-end' server. If we could perform all the Django translations beforehand, then those template files could live on S3. Thus, no Django overhead on the front end, and no requests to the back end that don't require data.

Comment: Is it a static file then, rather than a template?